# Go to declaration don't work with linked resources

Tags: eclipse

My Problem is that `Go to declaration` doesn't work with linked resources.

I insert a project into eclipse as a linked resource. ( all the src files)

But now the `Go to declaration` Button doesn't work.

Error message: `Could not find symbol 'xxx' in index`